# Early to late 80s sci fi anime: spaceship with the last of humanity fleeing alien forces

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime, spaceship

I have been trying to find details of this movie or series for years without any luck. What I remember is a space ship with the last of humanity on board running away from alien forces.

They find a planet to settle on but, the aliens have beaten them to it and attack them. In the chaos a lady who is a mother to one of the crew is left behind on the planet as they evacuate. When they move away from the planet the lady's daughter breaks down and cries for her in the arms of a close friend; as they look back at the planet they see a ghostly apparition of her mother over the planet.

In the next episode or movie the mother somehow comes back unharmed but turns out to be an alien in disguise.

Any ideas?